# tilted axis 2D plot where x y axis make 60 degree rather than 90

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, gnuplot, octave

I want to plot a distribution in hexagonal lattice like following.

I want to present this data as 2D colormap or bar chart. Does any one know how to do this? I am familiar with octave, python, gnuplot, excel, matlab.

```
                 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
               2   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
            3    3   3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3
              2   2   2  2  2  2  2  2  2
                1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: What form does you data have?  For example, the center point of each bin and a z-value?  Or, (x,y) pairs from which you want to calculate the density in each hexagon?  or ??  (For the first case, why not just plot colored hexagons in a scatter plot, and for the second case, `hexbin` should work.

Comment: The form of data if exactly like shown in the question. It is a text file written by a fortran program. It is like first case, i.e., data is z values. How do I plot colored hexagones? I tried loading it by a=load("dist.dat") in octave but get error (inconsistent number of columns). I cannot accomodate them in erxcel sheet either.

Comment: How do you know which hexagon corresponds to which Z value?  Or are you saying you have a text file that when you print it looks like a histogram?

Comment: These 44 numbers represent a physical quantity for 44 hexagonal mesh. If each number is presented as hexagonal bars of different height (according to the value) or colormap then purpose will be served. Any other  way to represent them?

Comment: Sorry for not answering completely. I have a text file which is cartogram (in numbers) for hexagonal lattice. I want to represent the cartogram in numbers as 2D colormap or 3D hexagonal bar chart. I gave number in the question as example. the text file exactly look like the arrangement of numbers in the question only difference being the numbers are multi-digit real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`patch`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) in MATLAB.

```
data = cellfun(@(x) textscan(x, '%f')', importdata('data.txt', sprintf('\n')));
rowLen = cellfun(@numel, data);
nPoints = sum(rowLen);

centerCells = arrayfun(@(l,r) [(-l+1:2:l-1)'*sin(pi/3) -r*1.5*ones(l,1)], ...
    rowLen', 1:numel(rowLen), 'UniformOutput', false);
centers = vertcat(centerCells{:});

hx = linspace(0,2*pi,7)'; 
vertices = reshape(...
            bsxfun(@plus, permute(sin([hx pi/2+hx]), [1 3 2]), ...
                          permute(centers, [3 1 2])), 7 * nPoints, 2);
faces = reshape(1:7*nPoints, 7, nPoints)';
colorData = vertcat(data{:});

patch('Vertices', vertices, 'Faces', faces, ...
    'FaceColor', 'flat', 'FaceVertexCData', colorData); 
axis equal
```

and this produces
[image]

Read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) if you need to change the color scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe this should work the way I intend. I shall try this with my data. I am only familiar with MATLAB (not expert like you). Are the instruction exact or I substitute for @(x),@numel in cellfun and @(l,r) in arrayfun. What if arrayfun.m is not available? (help arrayfun = arrayfun.m not found.)Thanks gain.

Comment: mohsen I am working on it. I read about functions and feel the instructions are exact. Which version matlab did you use for the example? I shall also try to do it in octave as it is more available to me. Thanks.

Comment: @sincerenice `arrayfun` and `cellfun` are builtin functions in MATLAB. You don't need to replace anything but the file name. I have tested it on MATLAB 2011a and 2012b, and works fine on both. Not sure about octave though. In case you find the answer correct, select it as an answer to help the community.

Comment: Will it work with any no of numbers? In question I used 44 numbers but in practice there will be many numbers (300 to 600). Would I need to change something depending on size of the problem? I am trying to do this with octave 3.6.1. and matlab-6.5 but not able to do. I will be able to do once I understand all the instructions completely. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, it works with any number of lines. Nothing is hard coded. What goes wrong when you run it on MATLAB 6.5?

Comment: Error with first instruction at ( after @     
             >> data = cellfun(@(x), textscan(x, '%f')', importdata('16feb.1gg', sprintf('\n')));
??? data = cellfun(@(x), textscan(x, '%f')', importdata('16feb.1gg', sprintf('\n')));
                    |
Error: "identifier" expected, "(" found.

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason but you shouldn't have a comma after @(x)

Comment: I am able to produce desired result.Thanks. Is it possible to print the corresponding numbers in the hexagons? Can I print 2 or more sets of no one below other in the hexagons if I have more sets of number?